# How can I use software that is not "safe"?

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

I've been trying to use drawing/painting software like Inkscape and krita but they won't open because the software may not be "safe" for my Mac. Does anybody know how to enable the software so that it will work?

Comment: Are you sure you want to run unsigned software given the amount of research you’ve done on what this feature is designed to do?

Answer (score 2):

just:
- Right-click (or control-click) the application in question and choose “Open”
- Click the “Open” button at the next dialog warning to launch the app anyway

more on http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/

Answer (score 0):

You can also go in to System Preferences > Security and Privacy and change Allow apps downloaded from "App Store and identified developers" to just "App Store"